# How to find out original IONIC version of an OLD project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I just need to clarify a bit these basic concepts because after searching the Web I still have not been clear.

I have been given a project based on IONIC to make modifications.
I have to install everything necessary to create the original work environment.

Is there any way to find out what version of ionic was used and install that same?

Could installing the latest IONIC release directly lead to problems with a project presumably carried out in another previous IONIC version?

But I also have doubts and I have assumed that since I will have to install nodejs, cordova and ionic, it is still better to install the latest version of IONIC because it will be the one that best integrates with the installation of the latest version of node and Cordova that I must install.

I'm a little worried because I do not know what to install from an existing ionic project. I want to do the most correct thing to finally end up generating and publishing the APP.

Thank you (sorry my English)

Comment: When you say an 'old project', do you have access to the actual source code, or only the actual application?

Comment: I have access to the source code. And i say Old but only wanted to say an It was created and published more or less later 2017 or even january 2018   Not very old. Thans

Comment: Could it be a clue if I could see the version of angular it is using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With functional app

If you can run the app in the browser, open the developer tools (usually Ctrl+Shift+I) and type this into the prompt in the Console tab:

```
ionic.version
```

It will print the ionic version, like this:

```
<< ionic.version
<- "1.3.2"
```

Note that in newer versions the `ionic` object is spelled with a capital letter `Ionic`.

### Without functional app

If you don't have a built working version, but have the sources, you can look at the `package.json` file that you should have it the root folder. Search for the `ionic-angular` package. It's version:

```
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
```

Should roughly match the Ionic used to build this.

---

Look, the browser console command even works on some production apps:
[image: example of querying ionic version]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used the package.json and findout my ionic-angular version is 3.9.2 . By the way I appreciate if you could help me with this problem in this stack:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51058413/i-can%C2%B4t-run-an-ionic-3-project-always-same-error