# I can´t run an IONIC 3 project. Always same error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

This IONIC project is not mine and it is IONIC 3 so I'm little lost so I appreciate any clue. 
I've been stuck in this for two days.

We have no contact with the one who developed the project for us and we wanted to take advantage of it to start programming using IONIC. Until now we used only cordova.
But first we need to start this project.
The same error is obtained if we try to boot on the BROWSER or ANDROID platform

IONIC error when execute in my IONIC project (for run in the browser):

```
ionic server



    Cannot find module "@app/env"
    at Object.521 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:6800:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.471 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:6492:74)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.466 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:6454:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:26:23)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1
```

Data about my IONIC proyect

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.10
Angular Core: 4.4.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.4.3
Node: 8.11.1
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36
```

**UPDATE MORE INFO ABOUT PROJECT:**

if I run this CLI :

> ionic doctor list

**This is the output:**

automatic-updates-off
npm-installed-locally
ionic-installed-locally
git-not-used
git-config-invalid
ionic-angular-update-available
ionic-angular-major-update-available
app-scripts-update-available
app-scripts-major-update-available
ionic-native-old-version-installed
ionic-native-update-available
ionic-native-major-update-available
unsaved-cordova-platforms
cordova-platforms-committed
default-cordova-bundle-id-used
viewport-fit-not-set

Do you think I must run?

> ionic doctor check

**This is link to package.json:**

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s3VzCgoFB3JQorIwkuF6pN-olImwCDc_)

[image]

Comment: From comments seen that ionic server is used to run an application or it's a typing mistake. Is that ionic serve or ionic sever?

Comment: I use:  ionic serve for run project. And as you can see in the capture, it execute in the browser. But even we have used CLI   ionic cordova run android --prod --release. But if we use all of this with a template project download from IONIC all warks OK so the IONIC -ANGULAR platform is OK.

Comment: Is there a way of create new IONIC project and then copy some stuffs from original project so we can repair something. It seem some configuration in the original old project is not OK. We  removed the android platform and added again but still same error.

Comment: We can create a project and copy contents. But I will not suggest that. Share package.json file.

Comment: I hared link to my JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps you can try to run your application:

1. Please install node dependencies if you have not done using `npm install`
2. Run application on the browser: `ionic serve`

For Android platform add below one more step after first step above: 
`ionic cordova platform add android` and then run using `ionic cordova run android`

Following link will give a reference to add/use enviorment variables in your Ionic project:

> https://github.com/gshigeto/ionic-environment-variables

Comment: Upgrade @ionic-native/core to 4.4.0. Can use commnad as npm install @ionic-native/core@4.4.0

Comment: I have upgraded de core as you say. At the end promt : updated 1 package but still same mesage in broser when I run 'ionic serve' I 'll copy/paste some WARNING when upgrade core just  in case they where important to notice them. Thanks for your clues

Comment: Very strange because this is a real project the developer compile and published. Now developer is not here but instruction are simple only we install ionic , cordova etc and we only try to run in browser. Need republish we little changes but still that strange error in the first note. Any idea about?

Comment: @Falinsito, the machine which tries to run an application is set up for an Ionic project right? If yes, just put a screenshot of project structure from file explorer. Will help you better when we know exactly what is missed to run your application.

Comment: IONIC is working so I have posted project screenshot in separate asnwer as you said. Thank you for your help Pradnya

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]Thank you Pradna Sinalkar for your help. 
here I post a capture of the project structure. If you need more specific in some folder or file tell me and I´ll post it.
We are very worried because we want recover the project.

We installed IONIC and node and cordova All is working.
We download a template proyect from IONIC and it run very well in browser.
¿The problem in our project could be width some actualization of current IONIC?

[image]

Comment: Share environment and tsconfig.json file. For issue not able to find @app/env, a path is incorrect.

Comment: Here you have LINK for my tsconfig.json  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LZ1m21HYkQbC1CQVCYc01ObnbI8qcV7u

Comment: I added screenshot current enviorement variables in windows 10 where try run IONIC project

Comment: In environments folder only one file is present, right? Named with environment.ts

Comment: I can see there are 6 files in enviorements folder and one of these files is enviorement.ts and this is a link to this file:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ewfEw-x8Fc1GiF49UCo95uNyDbVObWk7

Comment: If any link you can share for code, it will be great. According to your environment file in src, need to set tsconfig.json

Comment: this is my tsconfig.json file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LZ1m21HYkQbC1CQVCYc01ObnbI8qcV7u

Comment: Screenshot of files in my enviorement folder https://drive.google.com/open?id=14b6BKF3ELm4M-tXD0Sb4NNCWap1ByrX_      I suppose only  environment.ts is used. I do not know why are some other files here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173951/discussion-between-pradnya-sinalkar-and-falinsito).